# Make html layout and use it with JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table with some data:

```
            <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><h1>Name</h1></th>
                <th><h1>Picture</h1></th>
                <th><h1>Likes</h1></th>
                <th><h1>Time</h1></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    ***loop***
                <tr>
                    <td>{placeholder1}</td>
                    <td><img src="{placeholder2}" alt=""></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{placeholder3}</a></td>
                    <td>{placeholder4}</td>
                </tr>
                   ***end loop***
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have a js function who gets some data from server by POST request every 10 minutes. `<tr></tr>` block needs to be repeated several times.
HTML code become more and more complex and I need a solution with layouts and placeholders. I need a direction to search :)
All I need is:

1. Store `<tr></tr>` pattern with placeholders to insert it into my webpage. How could I achieve it with js?
2. How could I mark the places where I need data to be inserted?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework, jquery for example? or is it just vanilla javascript?

Comment: You can use Vue.js which is recommended by Laravel. If your data is from a Javascript function the two will implement easily.

Comment: @DavidLavieri, I use jq.

Comment: @ScottPlunkett, thanks, I'll try

Comment: its simple, just append the <tr></tr> blocks using .append() function in JQ. and if you want to maintain the record just create a array and push id's of appended rows and in next request just check if id exist in array, if yes then leave it, if No then append the <tr></tr> and also push it into array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since you are using jQuery,

This may be your HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody id="myTableBody">
    <!-- Your elements will be placed here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I will assume you are using $.ajax or $.post in either of those, add a callback function property `success`

```
$.ajax({
  // ... your properties,
  success: function(data) {
    // basic template for of your "tr"
    var trTemplate = [
      '<tr>',
      '<td></td>',
      '<td><img src="" alt=""></td>',
      '<td><a href="#"></a></td>',
      '<td></td>',
      '</tr>'
    ].join('')

    // get the tbody elemen
    var $myBody = $('#myTableBody')

    // if you want to clean up the current content of $myBody, 
    // if it is not the case just remove the following line
    $myBody.empty()

    // assuming data is an array of elements / entities
    data.forEach(function(element){
      var $tr = $(trTemplate)

      $tr.find('td').eq(0).text(element.placeholder1)
      $tr.find('img').attr('src', element.placeholder2)
      $tr.find('td').eq(2).text(element.placeholder3)
      $tr.find('td').eq(3).text(element.placeholder4)

      $myBody.append($tr)
    })

  }
})
```

This is example of how you could do it, there are many ways to improve this for performance and so on. Please use it only as reference

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then this is pretty straightforward. You need to id your  elements so that you can reference them individually. Say you start with:

```
<tr id="tr-0" >
   content...
</tr>
```

and then in javascript..

```
var id = $('#tr-0').attr('id');
var num = parseInt(id.substring(3));
num++;

$('#tr-0').after('<tr id='+num+'>content...</tr>');
```

obviously you need to figure how you're getting the content for each row but hopefully you can see that it wouldn't be too hard to fill each row with custom data.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use jQuery, simpler ways exist. jQuery will require you to add additional steps that aren't really necessary. If you want to use as few Javascript packages as possible, go with jQuery.

But, I highly recommend Vue.js for Laravel projects. There are instructions from Laracasts on how to set it up. But, I have created a jsfiddle with a working set of Vue.js with the `v-for` directive. [Checkout the JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/L42cg3we/1/)

If you have questions, I'll answer as much as I can.